# If a property has no explicit return what is it returning?

Tags: vb.net

I have some code I inherited which has a lot of warnings that I would like to get removed. Many are of the form `Property '<propertyname>' doesn't return a value on all code paths`. I know why it is saying this, I'm just trying to determine what the correct 0 impact way of fixing this is.

The original code is this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property LevelName() As String Implements IMember.LevelName
    Get

    End Get
End Property
```

My first thought was that I could just put a `Return Nothing` statement in there but I notice if I decompile it in Reflector it gives me this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property LevelName As String
    Get
        Dim LevelName As String
        Return LevelName
    End Get
End Property
```

Unfortuantely if I put this in my code (having changed the local variable name to avoid collisions) it then complains that it is being used before it has been assigned a value.

Try to analyze IL in LinqPad (not sure if this is a good test or not) reveals that the empty method is the same as the above that Reflector gave me but it is different from `return Nothing` and `return ""`.

What can I use to get rid of this warning while guaranteeing the code runs 100% the same?

**Edit:** I thought I'd include the IL that LinqPad is giving me for the various situations:

Empty get:

```
IL_0000:  ldloc.0     
IL_0001:  ret
```

Explicit empty string returned:

```
IL_0000:  ldstr       ""
IL_0005:  ret
```

Explicit Nothing Returned:

```
IL_0000:  ldnull      
IL_0001:  ret
```

I'm not sure what `ldloc.0` does here. I'm wondering if it is trying to get something from a register which will be null and if that is therefore the same as ldnull in this situation but I havent' ever really studied IL much before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** have a return statement! (Even if VB allows you to leave it out, my feeling as programmer says to me that one must belong here.)

```
Public ReadOnly Property LevelName() As String Implements IMember.LevelName 
    Get 
        Return Nothing
    End Get 
End Property
```

Or

```
Public ReadOnly Property LevelName() As String Implements IMember.LevelName 
    Get 
        Return ""
    End Get 
End Property
```

---

The code decompiled from IL does not always work, because in IL you can do things that are not possible in VB. In general, high-level languages like VB or c# are much more restrictive than low-level languages like assembler or IL (which is a kind of assembler).

Comment: Actually that is empirically not true. This code compiles and runs fine without a return statement, it just throws compiler warnings (not errors). And the above two suggestions don't seem to compile to the same IL as the empty getter which is why I am a little nervous of making the change to one of these two (though my instincts said that the first would be the best).

Comment: A getter or a function without a return-statement just does not make a lot of sense. VB is very forgiving and returns the default value for a type, if you do not specify a return statement; however, this is a very bad programming style and does not express your intention. Someone reading the code does not know if the code is incomplete or if it is supposed to return `Nothing`. Therefore the warning of the compiler. I strongly urge you to add a `Return Nothing`!

Comment: If it is impossible to get code that compiels to the same thing is it possible to in some tell the compiler to not warn me about certain blocks of code so I can just say "I know this is wrong but I don't care, please never tell me again" or something similar...

Comment: Sadly I am that guy. This is code I inherited and I am trying to make it stop spitting warnings all over the place when I compile. Sadly as you say I don't know what it should be returning or is returning at the moment which is why I am very nervous about assigning it something. `Return Nothing` does seem to be what I want and your comment "VB is very forgiving and returns the default value for a type, if you do not specify a return statement" seems to be the answer I want. Don't suppose you have a reference for that do you?

Comment: The only question that matters here is, which value does the function return? It does return `Nothing` without return statement. Therefore, you do not risk anything by improving the getter and adding a return statement. The compiler adds an invisible `Dim LevelName As String` (that is initialized with `Nothing`) because in VB6 you returned a value by assigning it to this variable. This variable is obsolete in VB.NET

Comment: Cool. I think you've convinced me enough now. I'll blame you if our code stops working tomorrow. ;-) But seriosuly, thanks for the feedback. You have confirmed all my suppositions. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `ldloc.0` instruction is loading a local variable that is then returned in the next statement.  The code, being empty, doesn't declare any variables, so you may wonder what this is.  This phantom local is the variable that VB automatically creates with the same name as the function or property.  If you have a branch without a return, it returns this variable for you.  This is mostly a legacy/compatibility feature by now as most people will use the `Return` statement and make their own variables.

Since this variable is just defined and returned without ever being assigned to, you can see that Oliver's comment to his answer that VB will return the default value for the type is correct. `Return Nothing` is the best match for this case.  The IL may be different, but the behavior will be the same.  (The machine code may come out the same, but I don't try to guess at what the JITter does.)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I need to learn IL so I can understand these things myself. ;-)